# Type [object Object] does not have 'ɵmod' property

Tags: angular, angular-material, migration

```
Uncaught Error: Type [object Object] does not have 'ɵmod' property.
    at getNgModuleDef (core.js:1132:1)
    at recurse (core.js:25372:1)
    at recurse (core.js:25383:1)
    at recurse (core.js:25383:1)
    at registerNgModuleType (core.js:25368:1)
    at new NgModuleFactory$1 (core.js:25482:1)
    at compileNgModuleFactory__POST_R3__ (core.js:29182:1)
    at PlatformRef.bootstrapModule (core.js:29432:1)
    at 14431 (main.ts:11:26)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
    at __webpack_exec__ (util.inspect:1:1)
    at util.inspect:1:1
    at __webpack_require__.O (chunk loaded:25:1)
    at util.inspect:1:1
    at webpackJsonpCallback (jsonp chunk loading:72:1)
    at main.js:1:75
```

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "ingo-iv-web",
  "version": "1.1.0",
  "license": "PrimeNG Commercial",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --port=process.env.PORT",
    "build": "webpack",
    "test": "karma start ./karma.conf.js",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "protractor ./protractor.conf.js",
    "prepree2e": "npm start",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false --quiet"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^12.2.17",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "^12.2.17",
    "@angular/compiler": "^12.2.17",
    "@angular/core": "^12.2.17",
    "@angular/forms": "^12.2.17",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^12.2.17",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^12.2.17",
    "@angular/router": "^12.2.17",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "4.2.0",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "4.2.0",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "4.2.0",
    "@sentry/browser": "^5.19.1",
    "apexcharts": "^3.35.5",
    "chart.js": "^2.1.3",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "exceljs": "^1.10.0",
    "file-saver": "^1.3.8",
    "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
    "fullcalendar": "^3.1.0",
    "intl": "^1.2.5",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "jspdf": "^1.5.3",
    "jspdf-autotable": "^3.5.28",
    "mingcute_icon": "^2.7.1",
    "moment": "^2.17.1",
    "nanoscroller": "0.8.7",
    "ng-apexcharts": "1.6.0",
    "ng-fullcalendar": "^2.0.3",
    "ng-http-loader": "^0.3.3",
    "ngx-csv": "^0.3.2",
    "ngx-papaparse": "^5.1.0",
    "ngx-permissions": "^8.1.1",
    "remixicon": "^2.5.0",
    "rxjs": "6.5.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.3",
    "simple-line-icons": "^2.4.1",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.2.2",
    "xlsx": "^0.18.5",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^12.2.18",
    "@angular/cli": "^12.2.18",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^12.2.17",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.191",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "autoprefixer": "^6.5.3",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "stylus-loader": "^2.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.3",
    "typescript": "^4.2.3",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack": "^4.39.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.15.1"
  }
}
```

**When compiled successfully without errors, the browser doesn't respond, and the above error is displayed.**

** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **

√ Compiled successfully.
✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.

7 unchanged chunks

Build at: 2024-01-11T12:21:58.547Z - Hash: e6b51174fba88ec815a1 - Time: 5794ms

√ Compiled successfully.

Comment: When did this error start occurring? I noticed your @angular/cdk version is 8, while everything else is 12.

Comment: @BizzyBob ,When migrating from Angular version 11 to 12, I encountered this error.

Comment: try deleting node modules and npm i

Comment: @Unknown, I tried this, but the same error was thrown.